# Browser doesn't refresh animation on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Yesterday I've asked why `window.requestAnimationFrame()` gave me an error and thanks to an user now it works. 
I am trying to make an animation of a ball that moves and goes in to a basket.
I am using the `clearRect()` function to clear the canvas and redraw everything so that it seems that the ball moves, but instead of the result that I wanted I get a static image without any ball and after 5 seconds the ball reappears in the basket. My guess is that the browser doesn't refresh the animation until it's finished (I could be wrong, it's my first canvas project). Here is the piece of my code that gives me problems

```
const tabx=800, taby=100; //backboard position
var canvas, ctx;
function init(z){ //z is the status, at the start of the animation is 0, than goes to 1
    document.getElementById("corpo").innerHTML="<canvas id='mycanvas' width='1000' height='600'></canvas><button onclick='start()'>start</button>"
    canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //backboard
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.rect(tabx,taby,180,100);
    ctx.stroke();

    //basket
    ctx.scale(1,0.5);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(890,320,35, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(855,320);
    ctx.lineTo(865,445);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(925,320);
    ctx.lineTo(915,445);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.scale(1,0.15);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(890,2980,25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); //setting to default

    if(z==0)
        start();
function start(){
    var x1,y1,a,b,c,denom;

    //generating ball position
    x1=(Math.random()*500)+100;
    y1=(Math.random()*200)+300;

    canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //setting the medium point of the parabola
    x2=(x1+890)/2;
    y2=((y1+320)/2)-300;

    //setting the final point of the parabola
    x3=tabx+90;
    y3=taby+90;

    //finding the parabola equation
    denom=(x1-x2) * (x1-x3) * (x2-x3);
    a=(x3 * (y2-y1) + x2 * (y1-y3) + x1 * (y3-y2)) / denom;
    b=(x3*x3 * (y1-y2) + x2*x2 * (y3-y1) + x1*x1 * (y2-y3)) / denom;
    c=(x2 * x3 * (x2-x3) * y1+x3 * x1 * (x3-x1) * y2+x1 * x2 * (x1-x2) * y3) / denom;

    drawball(a,b,c,x1,y1);
}
function drawball(a,b,c,x1,y1){
    canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //drawing the ball
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1,y1,25,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    if(x1<x3){
        sleep(500);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
        init(1); //calling init() for redrawing without passing through start()
        y1=a*(x1*x1)+b*x1+c;
        x1+=10;

        //drawing the next ball
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { drawball(a,b,c,x1,y1) } );
    }
}
```

If I remove the `clearRect()` function i get an animation of the ball going towards the basket while it leaves a trail of balls behind itself. 
Thank you for your help.

Here is the sleep function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
       if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "sleep" ... `sleep(500);` - not a javascript function ... debugging 101: browser developer tools console - check it for errors - https://jsfiddle.net/r97jku1q/

Comment: Yes it's not a javascript function, I took it from the internet, I'll add its code to the post

Comment: Thanks you for your fixings to the code! Now it works fine

Comment: `I took it from the internet` - that's trouble - `Here is the sleep function:`  never ever do that in javascipt